# ggplot's qplot does not execute on sourcing

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-faq

Let's assume I have 2 source files, the first one named `example1.r` and the second one `example2.r` (given below).

**example1.r**

```
plot(1:10,1:10)
```

**example2.r**

```
qplot(1:10,1:10)
```

When I source example1.r, the graph is drawn. It does not, however, when I source example2.r. What is the solution here?

(qplot in example2.r is [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/)'s function)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

*Update*:

- **.R files:** `source`'s option `print.eval=TRUE` will lead to printing behaviour of the evaluation result like in the interactive command line.

> `source("Script.R", print.eval=TRUE)`

- **.Rnw files:** `knitr` by default emulates the behaviour of the interactive command line wrt. `print`ing. Note that `knitr` can be specified as Sweaving engine also for R package vignettes.

---

*This is my original answer. But note that this workaround is IMHO completely obsolete now (and it always was good for a small lazy niche only).*

This is the famous [FAQ 7.22: Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f).

For grid graphics like ggplot2 or lattice, you need to print the graphics object in order to actually draw it.

Interactively on the command line this is done automatically. Everywhere else (inside files to be sourced, loops, functions, Sweave chunks) you need to print it explicitly.

```
print (qplot (1 : 10, 1 : 10))
```

Alternatively, you can redefine `qplot` to do the printing:

```
qplot <- function (x, y = NULL, z = NULL, ...) {
  p <- ggplot2::qplot (x = x, y = y, z = z, ...)
  print (p)
}
```

(this changes the axis labels to x and y).

I use this approach in vignettes where I want to write code exactly as a user in an interactive session would type it.

Comment: Minor point: you don't need `invisible(p)` since `print(p)` returns `p`.

Comment: Thanks Richie, `print (p)` returns actually `invisible (p)` - which is what I want (if it would be visible, using it from the command line would produced the plots twice). Edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1)! I was going nuts trying to figure this out for a couple of hours. I have two additional relevant questions, if you don't mind: 1) Will redefining `qplot()` shown above work nicely with `ggplot2`'s layering functions? 2) Is similar redefinition necessary for the other `ggplot2`'s function, producing output - `ggplot()`?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: Where I have used this approach so far, it worked. But I'm using it less and less as I hardly ever `source` .R files but instead use .Rnw files. I've almost completely changed to using `knitr` instead of `Sweave`, and `knitr` by default emulates the `print` behaviour of the R command line, so the answer is largeyl obsolete for me.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the comment! However, I didn't understand your answer in regard to `ggplot` - does it also require redefinition, similarly to the one for `qplot`?

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes if you use `ggplot ()` instead of `qplot ()` you can and need to apply the same strategy.

Comment: I tried to integrate your advice with my project's environment and so far it failed. I created a separate question for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851465/environment-error-when-trying-to-use-redefined-ggplotqplot. Would greatly appreciate, if you could take a look and help! Thank you!

Comment: I have a slightly similar problem, I calling the R script using Rscript but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181206/running-rscript-containing-ggplot-from-linux-command-line-through-xterm