# Save ggplot within a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to save a ggplot within a function using graphics devices. But I found the code produces empty graphs. Below is a very very simple example.

```
library(ggplot2)
ff <- function(){
  jpeg("a.jpg")
  qplot(1:20, 1:20)
  dev.off()
}
ff()
```

If I only run the content of the function, everything is fine. I know that using ggsave() will do the thing that I want, but I am just wondering why jpeg() plus dev.off() doesn't work. I tried this with different versions of R, and the problem persists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ggplot's qplot does not execute on sourcing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675066/ggplots-qplot-does-not-execute-on-sourcing)

Comment: @gsk3 This question is in fact subtly different.  Sufficient, in my view, to keep it open.  The question you link to tries to display plots.  This question wants to save a ggplot.  So the correct answer in this case is to use `ggsave`, whereas the correct answer in the linked question is to use `print(p)`

Comment: @Andrie: They say they know about ggsave, though; which makes the correct answer to "why jpeg() plus dev.off() doesn't work" the same as the linked question.  You're right that it's subtly different and therefore probably worth keeping around though.

Comment: @gsk3 Thank you very much. I should have invested more before asking.

Comment: So it _was_ a duplicate.

Answer (score 47):

You should use `ggsave` instead of the `jpeg(); print(p); dev.off()` sequence.  `ggsave` is a wrapper that does exactly what you intend to do with your function, except that it offers more options and versatility.  You can specify the type of output explicitly, e.g. jpg or pdf, or it will guess from your filename extension.

So your code might become something like:

```
p <- qplot(1:20, 1:20)
ggsave(filename="a.jpg", plot=p)
```

See `?ggsave` for more details

---

The reason why the original behaviour in your code doesn't worked is indeed a frequently asked question (on [stackoverlflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675066/ggplots-qplot-does-not-execute-on-sourcing/6675610#6675610) as well as the [R FAQs on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f)).  You need to insert a `print` statement to print the plot.  In the interactive console, the print is silently execututed in the background.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is indeed better to use `ggsave`. But I am modifying existing codes to replace default plotting system with ggplot, so I prefer sticking to `jpeg(); print(p); dev.off()` sequence.

Comment: when i use ggsave within a loop the image loses colors and the legend

Answer (score 18):

These plots have to be printed:

```
ff <- function(){
  jpeg("a.jpg")
  p <- qplot(1:20, 1:20)
  print(p)
  dev.off()
}
ff()
```

This is a very [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675066/ggplots-qplot-does-not-execute-on-sourcing) mistake.

Comment: Although your answer is true, it is far better to use the `ggsave` function to save plots

Comment: @joran Thank you very much! I should have investigated more before asking.