# How can I save a plot as an image on the disk?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice, r-faq

I plot a simple [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) using R.
I would like to save that image as PNG or JPEG. Is it possible to do it automatically? (via code)

There are two different questions: First, I am already looking at the plot on my monitor and I would like to save it as is. Second, I have not yet generated the plot, but I would like to directly save it to disk when I execute my plotting code.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

There are two closely-related questions, and an answer for each.

---

### 1. An image will be generated in future in my script, how do I save it to disk?

To save a plot, you need to do the following:

1. Open a device, using `png()`, `bmp()`, `pdf()` or similar
2. Plot your model
3. Close the device using `dev.off()`

Some example code for saving the plot to a `png` file:

```
fit <- lm(some ~ model)

png(filename="your/file/location/name.png")
plot(fit)
dev.off()
```

This is described in the (combined) help page for the graphical formats `?png`, `?bmp`, `?jpeg` and `?tiff` as well as in the separate help page for `?pdf`.

Note however that the image might look different on disk to the same plot directly plotted to your screen, for example if you have resized the on-screen window.

---

Note that if your plot is made by either `lattice` or `ggplot2` you have to explicitly print the plot.  See this answer that explains this in more detail and also links to the R FAQ: [ggplot's qplot does not execute on sourcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675066/ggplots-qplot-does-not-execute-on-sourcing/6675610#6675610)

---

### 2. I'm currently looking at a plot on my screen and I want to copy it 'as-is' to disk.

```
dev.print(pdf, 'filename.pdf')
```

This should copy the image perfectly, respecting any resizing you have done to the interactive window. You can, as in the first part of this answer, replace `pdf` with other filetypes such as `png`.

Comment: if you not set the path, like png(filename="name.png"), you can know the directory of save with `getwd()`

Comment: I have extended this answer to include a reference to `dev.print`. There are two closely-related questions which I think need different answers. The second sub-question is basically "How do I save an image that I have already plotted to my screen?".  Apologies if my editting isn't very good, feel free to improve on my edits.

Comment: How do I do this when R asks for a "Selection"? For example If I use `m3=garchFit(~arma(3,0)+garch(1,1))` and `plot(m3)`.

Comment: How can I save the figure with dpi=3000

Comment: 8 years using R without knowing I could actually save the dev opened on my screen in a file. I guess I didn't need that... but thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 94):

If you want to keep seeing the plot in R, another option is to use `dev.copy`:

```
X11 ()
plot (x,y)

dev.copy(jpeg,filename="plot.jpg");
dev.off ();
```

If you reach a clutter of too many plot windows in R, use `graphics.off()` to close all of the plot windows.

Comment: Great answer!  This allows you to experiment with plots via X, until you're happy with the results, and then save them on the spot.  This is usually the most convenient mode of operation.

Comment: `dev.print` is better as it copies the image from the screen exactly. `dev.copy` forces every image to be square by default. This is frustrating if you've set up everything nicely interactively

Comment: I use `dev.print()` with the width and height parameters to define the dimensions. e.g. 
`dev.copy(device = png, filename = 'MyPlot.png', width = 1000, height = 500)
dev.off()`

Answer (score 86):

If you use `ggplot2` the preferred way of saving is to use `ggsave`. First you have to plot, after creating the plot you call `ggsave`:

```
ggplot(...)
ggsave("plot.png")
```

The format of the image is determined by the extension you choose for the filename. Additional parameters can be passed to `ggsave`, notably `width`, `height`, and `dpi`.

Comment: This works well in a loop, dev.off didn't work for me

Comment: the upside of this is the consistent API and no need to mess with turning on and off devices

Comment: Unlike solutions with `dev`, this solution worked on a virtual machine without graphic devices.

Comment: I wish there was a powerful, yet simple, approach like this for ALL plots in R. Anyway, my vote goes here.

Comment: Still valid almost 7 Years on! Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

Like this

```
png('filename.png')
# make plot
dev.off()
```

or this

```
# sometimes plots do better in vector graphics
svg('filename.svg')
# make plot
dev.off()
```

or this

```
pdf('filename.pdf')
# make plot
dev.off()
```

And probably others too. They're all listed together in the help pages.

Comment: Is there any way for R to infer the file extension automatically (i.e. based on the function)? It seems tedious to have to change the filename as well as the function used.

Answer (score 12):

For the first question, I find `dev.print` to be the best when working interactively. First, you set up your plot visually and when you are happy with what you see, you can ask R to save the current plot to disk

```
dev.print(pdf, file="filename.pdf");
```

You can replace `pdf` with other formats such as `png`.

This will copy the image exactly as you see it on screen. The problem with `dev.copy` is that the image is often different and doesn't remember the window size and aspect ratio - it forces the plot to be square by default.

For the second question, (as others have already answered), you must direct the output to disk before you execute your plotting commands

```
pdf('filename.pdf')
plot( yourdata )
points (some_more_data)
dev.off() # to complete the writing process and return output to your monitor
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/), there is a special menu to save your plot as any format you like and at any resolution you choose.

Comment: This also exists in the R GUI on Windows, at least.

Comment: sometimes this mysteriously fails for me, but calling a function always works

Answer (score 4):

If you open a device using `png()`, `bmp()`, `pdf()` etc. as suggested by ***Andrie*** (the best answer), the windows with plots will not pop up open, just *.png, *bmp or *.pdf files will be created. This is convenient in massive calculations, since R can handle only limited number of graphic windows.

However, if you want to see the plots and also have them saved, call `savePlot(filename, type)` after the plots are drawn and the window containing them is active.

Answer (score 3):

```
plotpath<- file.path(path, "PLOT_name", paste("plot_", file, ".png", sep=""))

png(filename=plotpath)

plot(x, y, main=file)

dev.off()
```

Comment: a combination of what is mentioned above and                                          http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/                                                               It worked out for me!

Answer (score 0):

To add to these answers, if you have an R script containing calls that generate plots to screen (the native device), then these can all be saved to a [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) file (the default device for a noninteractive shell) "Rplots.pdf" (the default name) by redirecting the script into R from the terminal (assuming you are running Linux or OS X), e.g.:

```
R < myscript.R --no-save
```

This could be converted to [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) or [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, one wants to both save and print a base R plot. I spent a bit of time and came up with this utility function:

```
x = 1:10

basesave = function(expr, filename, print=T) {
  #extension
  exten = stringr::str_match(filename, "\\.(\\w+)$")[, 2]

  switch(exten,
         png = {
           png(filename)
           eval(expr, envir = parent.frame())
           dev.off()
         },
         {stop("filetype not recognized")})


  #print?
  if (print) eval(expr, envir = parent.frame())

  invisible(NULL)
}

#plots, but doesn't save
plot(x)

#saves, but doesn't plot
png("test.png")
plot(x)
dev.off()

#both
basesave(quote(plot(x)), "test.png")

#works with pipe too
quote(plot(x)) %>% basesave("test.png")
```

Note that one must use `quote`, otherwise the `plot(x)` call is run in the global environment and `NULL` gets passed to `basesave()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
dev.copy(png,'path/pngFile.png')
plot(YData ~ XData, data = mydata)
dev.off()
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*

Comment: Perhaps somebody else can chime it? Is this a bogus answer or not?