# Using R legend (graphics package), fill legend left to right instead of top to bottom

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to plot a legend at the bottom of a main plot area comprised of multiple small plots (4 rows x 5 columns). I figured out how to center the legend at the bottom with the aid of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12402894/743568). I'm interested in having a horizontal legend, so I tried to use `legend(x="center",lbls, horiz=TRUE)`, which would have served my purposes - except that my labels are too long and it goes off the plot area. I decided that a 2 row x 4 column layout will work best (I have 8 labels).

However, `legend(x="center",lbls, ncol = 4)` fills in the columns first (i.e. top to bottom), and I'd like to fill in by row first (i.e. left to right). Is there a workaround for this that doesn't involve using multiple legends?

Comment: Can't you just change lbls?

Comment: @Marichyasana I was hoping to manage without doing that, because I also have a rather complicated color vector defined for the fill, mashing subsets of three color palettes together. (Basically, I was wondering if there was an argument to legend that I'd missed, but I guess not?)