# Using R, how to capture the bitmap of a plot?

Tags: r

I'd like to capture the output of the following plot to a variable containing a bitmap, in R:

```
require(stats)
plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi) # see ?plot.function
```

[image]

Comment: Is saving it to a file fine, or do you need C# to grab the data directly e.g. using a pipe.

Comment: For speed, I would prefer if it didn't involve writes to the hard drive (I'm generating hundreds of these plots). R.NET has excellent support for passing variables back and forth from R to .NET, so if I could capture that bitmap into a variable in R, then we would have a solution.

Comment: As an aside, the reason I want to do this is that R.NET suppresses graphics output, so I want to capture this plot to a bitmap, and then display from a C# console app using WinForms. As an aside, this technique of capturing a bitmap of a plots perfectly with Mathematica.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This saves a bitmap file on the harddrive:

```
bmp("spam.bmp")
plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi)    
dev.off()
```

Googling `R save bitmap` get's you this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `magick` package:

```r
img <- magick::image_graph(width = 256, height = 256, res = 96, pointsize = 1, clip = FALSE)
plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi)
dev.off()
img
#>   format width height colorspace matte filesize density
#> 1    PNG   256    256       sRGB  TRUE        0 +72x+72
arr <- magick::image_data(img)
str(arr)
#> num [1:256, 1:256, 1:4] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```