# R reads .tiff image in low resolution

Tags: r, import, tiff

I want to load a background map (.tiff) in r, which is a TK200 map. Then i want to plot it with the normal plot() and then export it as a bmp. The export is only a low resolution.
R reads this tiff with somehow low resolution. This is not what I need. How can I import the tiff in a high resolution?

```
tk_200 <- raster(".../CC7910CO.tif")

> tk_200
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 14232, 15753, 224196696  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 6.3400704257022, 6.34007042570224  (x, y)
extent     : 3375641.35, 3475516.47941609, 5317939, 5408170.88229859  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : //aare/dpool/Topographie/TK200/Daten_unsortiert/Originaldaten/T+£K200-Raster/CC7910CO.TIF 
names      : CC7910CO 
values     : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

{bmp(file=path),
     width = 1600, height = 1300, units = "px", pointsize = 10)

plot(tk_200)

dev.off()}

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This question is not clear enough and perhaps you need to better explain what you want. I do not think what you get is of a lower resolution compared with the original data. What are the dimensions of the original data? isn't it **14232, 15753, 224196696**  **(nrow, ncol, ncell)**??! Maybe you are looking at your plot and think that is your .tiff file? If so, you are wrong.

Comment: Thank you for help. I tried to clarify my question. Is it possible to add pictures in the question?

Comment: Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387119/using-r-how-to-capture-the-bitmap-of-a-plot) or [here](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/saving-plot/).