# Saving a group of histograms in R as a data.frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am trying to save a histogram for every file in a list.  I cannot load more than 1 file at a time due to their large size.  Normally I would use a symbolic object name for each file's histogram and iterate the name for each item in the list.  I am having trouble figuring out how to do this in R so instead I attempt to save each hist as a column of a data.frame.  The code is as follows:

```
filelist <- list.files("dir/")
file.hist <- data.frame(check.rows = FALSE)
for(i in 1:length(filelist) {
  file <- read.csv(capture.output(cat("dir/", filelist[i], sep = "")))
  file.hist[[i]] <- hist(file$Value, breaks = 200)
}
```

The error message that results is:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(breaks = c(0, 200, : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 0
```

I have googled the error message and it seems like it might be related to how you go about initializing the data from although I have to admit that my brain is fried this close to Thanksgiving.  Has anyone out there dealt with an solved a similar problem?  I am not married to this approach.

Comment: Are you trying to save the image of a histogram? you should use an imaging device like the one referred to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Comment: If you _are_ trying to save the `hist` object, you should be using a list rather than a data frame (and you should pre-allocate the list to be the desired length up front).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments, I am trying to save the hist object. I will try the pre-allocated list method.

Comment: Try replacing `file.hist <- data.frame(check.rows = FALSE)` with `file.hist <- vector("list", length(filelist))` in your code.