# How to execute .r files to output figures?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I really need serious help here. I have been working with R the last month. I have been analyzing data, and plotting many visualizations using ggplot2. I have many `.r` files which includes data transformations and reading .csv ..etc

- My instructor wants me to show him my code or at least he want to execute and get all the figures I did. Can i run .r scripts (that includes codes to generate ggplot figures) on my instructor machine? - the good thing, the instructor machine has R too.

PS: The result can be as saving image to .JPEG to the instructor's machine.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save a plot as image on the disk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you have access to a terminal?

Comment: Hello All, thanks for your reply.. Windows 7..

Comment: If someone know the SVN, it is like Virtualbox. I need to install R there, and then the instructor himself want to execute the code. I was think of just having like .exe or executable.

Comment: Any suggestions, help ? Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with some more specifics rather than commenting on your question? It sounds like you just need to send your instructor your .R file(s) that include code to save the plots to local files.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! what you are saying is nearly what i want. I also updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that the R software where you will run your scripts, has all required packages installed. Second, make sure the data is somehow available. This should usually make all scripts runnable.

If you want to save ggplot-figures, use the `ggsave`-function after each plot is generated. This will save the last plot into the working directory (unless else specified).

Depending on how you wrote your code, you may create an "executable" script that calls all your relevant r-scripts via `source` command, so only one r-script needs to be compiled / sourced, and all others are automatically sourced from this "basefile".

An example of an "executable" script, which I usually create when working on new projects:

```
# --------------------------------
# load required libraries
# --------------------------------
library(sjmisc)
library(sjPlot)
# --------------------------------
# load data
# --------------------------------
david <- read_spss("Pat_Dateneingabe150511_MR_DL.sav")
# --------------------------------
# do all necessary recoding
# --------------------------------
source("recodes.R")
# --------------------------------
# create new variables / scales
# --------------------------------
source("Skalenbildung.R")
```

In this case, I have two large scripts *recodes.R* and *Skalenbildung.R*, which are sourced from this "base"-script. You could then add another script *plots.R* or whatever you may call it, and this script then contains all `ggplot`-commands to create the figures (don't forget to add `library(ggplot2)`). After each `ggplot(...)` add a `ggsave(...)` to save each plot.

Instead of using `ggsave`, you can also easily print all plots to a PDF file:

```
# --------------------------------
# plot all figures and save them to PDF
# --------------------------------
pdf("all-plots.pdf", width = 9, height = 7)
source("ggplot-figures.R")
dev.off()
```

In the *ggplot-figures.R*, you have all your ggplot-code that creates the plots you need, and these are saved to a single PDF.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, can you please explain your last point, which is creating executable script..etc ? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Everything is great.. And now, on the instructor's PC, we should run `Rscript filename` ?

Comment: I haven't used the basic R, but only RStudio. I'm not sure how to execute an R file from R console or R Software w/o IDE or which commands to be used. Perhaps start R, then `File -> Open Script` and then `Edit -> Run all`?

Comment: nevermind, Rscript filename should do everything fine!

Comment: I added an example, as alternativ to using `ggsave`. You can also easily create a PDF including all plots.