# R: How to save an image(..) on disk?

Tags: r, image

I want to save an image(..) on disk. I tried to save it like a plot as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk). However, this does not work, as I only get a white file.

I'm plotting a matrix containing world values using image(). And than I overlay a world map from maptools. When I just plot those together it works fine, but not on the file. Sorry I don't really have a reproducible example as my data is too large, but here is the code I'm using:

```
library("maptools")
jpeg(file = "results/originmaps/ram_artichoke2.jpg")
x11()
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
image(lon,lat,artichoke_mat,col = grey(seq(1, 0, length = 256)))  
data(wrld_simpl) 
plot(wrld_simpl,add=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong? or is there another way to save images? Thanks

Comment: Delete the `x11()` line.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks, that works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the call to `x11()`:

```
library("maptools")
jpeg(file = "ram_artichoke2.jpg")

par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
#image(lon,lat,artichoke_mat,col = grey(seq(1, 0, length = 256)))
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl)
dev.off()
```

This worked for me but I did not have your data for `lat` and `lon` and `artichoke_mat` to add in the data points of interest.