# Control alignment of two side-by-side plots in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I cannot figure out how to arrange two side-by-side plots as explained in the knitr graphics manual page 2 (http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/). I use the following MWE and the output is below. I would like them to be aligned as shown in the manual for the two cars plots (also on page 2 of the manual). The pdf is generated in RStudio (Knit to PDF).

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

## R Markdown

```{r,echo=FALSE,out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.width=3, fig.height=3}

barplot(1:4)
barplot(4:7)

```
````

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using ggplot2? Arranging graphs is much easier with this package.

Comment: I do not follow what you are trying to achieve could you clarify? When I use your code the figures look aligned.

Comment: @Otto_K I have to adhere to some very specific design guidelines, which I have figured out is easier to fulfill by doing customised graphs from base...

Comment: @Aneconomist I want them to be centered on the page (but still side by side), now they are aligned left...

Comment: @daved have you tried adding `fig.align='center'`?

Comment: @Aneconomist Yes, that produces a plot where they are on top of each other (albeit of course centered) - but just realised I can just put `\centering` just before the code fragment to have them both centered. I would however still like to be able to control the distance between the plots...

Comment: @daved does including  `fig.show='hold'` help?

Comment: The following is working for me: `{r,echo=FALSE, out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.width=3, fig.height=3,fig.show='hold',fig.align='center'}`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To center two plots you can add `fig.align='center'`to your chunk options. If it produces one plot above the other add also `fig.show='hold'`. The result should be two centered graphs. [image: Result]

So your final chunk option should look something like:

```
{r,echo=FALSE, out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.width=3, fig.height=3,fig.show='hold',fig.align='center'}
```

Comment: Ah, apologies, edited the question simultaneously as you wrote the answer - I'll make a new question regarding controlling the distance between the plots as this clearly solves the problem of centering them.

Comment: I had to omit the `out.width` to get it to plot, and omit the `fig.align='center'` so they would not stack.  Something may have changed in R Markdown or knittr in the last two years.

Comment: Do you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: This worked for me `{r fig_1, fig.width = 5, fig.height = 5, fig.show = "hold", out.width  =  "50%"}`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which worked for me: save the plots as files, then put the picture markdown on the same line (from [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-stack-two-images-horizontally-in-r-markdown/18941/2)).

```
## Show images
![](file1.pdf) ![](file2.pdf)
```

You can save ggplot plot objects with ggsave.

Base plots are a bit more complicated, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144203).

I'm putting this answer here because it helped me.  Whether it's better for you or not depends on your situation.