# par(mfrow = c(x, y)) not working in Rmd inline output

Tags: r, r-markdown, boxplot

I started working in Rmd as I prefer it's output after chunks to the console of an R script.

`par(mfrow = c(x, y))` however is not working for inline output. So an R chunk with

`par(mfrow = c(x, y)) 
boxplot()
boxplot()`

etc. does not show multiple plots. `boxplot()` is base R.

Is there a resource explaining why?

Answer (score 2):

The x and y in `par(mfrow = c(x, y))` designate the rows and columns, not the plots. You want something like:

```r
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(sample(120:200,200,TRUE), ncol=10, nrow=20)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(x = list(mat[,1], y = mat[,2]))
boxplot(x = list(mat[,3], y = mat[,4]))
```

[image]

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
``
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. See above for the issue.

Comment: If you defined your own boxplot function that does not use `base` graphics, then you might have to use something like `cowplot::plot_grid` (for `ggplot2` objects) or viewports for `grid` graphics.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115276/control-alignment-of-two-side-by-side-plots-in-knitr for chunk options that may help.

Comment: `boxplot()` is base R. Also I am not knitting so chunk options shouldn't make a difference AFAIK.