# How to download clear plot through rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I plot in rstudio, cannot see the number in plot, then I download as bigger size.
Whatever the png or jpeg format, even size is 2048 pixels, still cannot read the number in plot.
[image: you can download this image to see]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: what about `svg` format? It's vector and allows better zooming in, at least.  Though better if you provided some code . Someone would be able to tell how to increase the font sizes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

RStudio has known sizing issue of saving pictures plotted in the "plots" window. What I would do is to save the picture directly in code.

[Refer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

In short, what you can do is:

```
png(filename = pathToYourOutputPNG)    # create a png device
plot()   # write your plotting functions here
dev.off()    # close the device
```