# officer package function for adding an R plot to a presentation

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, powerpoint, officer

I am working on transfering my plots to a presentation using `officer` package in R.

A ggplot can be transferred using the `ph_with_gg()` function but what is the function to transfer normal R plots? I am not finding any such function in the package.

These are few of the resouces that I am refering:

[officer CRAN package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/officer.pdf)

[PowerPoint presentations generation](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/powerpoint.html)

Your help will be appreciated!

Regards

Comment: There must be something that already exists and I just want to know what are those functions simply using officer package.

Comment: I just made a package, export, that allows one to do just that and which is built on top of the officer package, see answer below!

Answer (score 6):

Save the plot you want to output as, say, a png file then use the `ph_with_img` function to place the image into your presentation.

The on-line help for the Powerpoint component of officer shows how to do this - see https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/powerpoint.html which you already referred to in your post.

If you don't know how to save a plot as an image please see (for example) this thread: [how to save a plot as image on the disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Comment: Thanks Stewart for your consideration! Working on code won't be taking place on just one laptop/PC. I am working on a large number of plots, so I don't think saving the plots as an imagine and then calling them to be shown on presentation will help!

Comment: Glad you found a way forward with rvg. In my own case I use officer and flextable to output to Word, with images stored to temporary locations when needed then incorporated into the word files. All my staff can run this, as the plot images are stored in a common network area accessible to all. The final document includes the images, not links to them, so the document / presentation does not depend on being on any particular PC. Anyway, I'm glad you've found a suitable solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way of doing this using `officer` and `rvg` packages together.

rvg also allows us to edit our plots on the slides.

The simple code to save a plot on slides is

```
ppt <- ph_with_vg(ppt, code = plot(), type = "body")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to export R graphs to Powerpoint you can also use the wrapper package `export` built on top of `officer` that just came out on CRAN, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and for demo
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export

Typical syntax is very easy and works for either base R, ggplot2 or lattice graphs, e.g. for a ggplot2 plot (but syntax is the same for base R plot, just call it after you made the plot):

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="ggplot2_plot.pptx", width=6, height=5)
```

You can also use it to export to Word, Excel, Latex or HTML and you can also use it to export statistical output of various R stats objects.