# Data labels for mean and percentiles in a distribution chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a custom chart to visualize a variable's distribution using `geom_density`. I added 3 vertical lines for a custom value, the 5th percentile and the 95th percentile.

How do I add labels for those lines?

I tried using `geom_text` but i don't know how to parameter the x and y variables

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataset, aes(x = dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`)) + 
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`[12]), 
             color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = quantile(dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`,
                                       0.05, na.rm = TRUE)), 
             color = "grey", size = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = quantile(dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`,
                                       0.95, na.rm = TRUE)), 
             color="grey", size=0.5) +

  geom_text(aes(x = dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`[12], 
                label = "Custom", y = 0), 
            colour = "red", angle = 0)
```

I'd like to obtain the following:

1. for the custom value, I'd like to add the label at the top of the chart, just to the right of the line
2. for the percentiles label, I'd like to add them in the middle of the chart; at the left of the line for the 5th percentile and right of the line for 95th percentile

Here is what I was able to obtain https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfRRK.png

And these are the first 50 lines of my dataset:

```
structure(list(`Respondent sequence number` = c(21029L, 21034L, 
21043L, 21056L, 21067L, 21085L, 21087L, 21105L, 21107L, 21109L, 
21110L, 21125L, 21129L, 21138L, 21141L, 21154L, 21193L, 21195L, 
21206L, 21215L, 21219L, 21221L, 21232L, 21239L, 21242L, 21247L, 
21256L, 21258L, 21287L, 21310L, 21325L, 21367L, 21380L, 21385L, 
21413L, 21418L, 21420L, 21423L, 21427L, 21432L, 21437L, 21441L, 
21444L, 21453L, 21466L, 21467L, 21477L, 21491L, 21494L, 21495L
), `Estimated percent body fat` = c(NA, 7.2, NA, NA, 24.1, 25.1, 
30.2, 23.6, 24.3, 31.4, NA, 14.1, 20.5, NA, 23.1, 30.6, 21, 20.9, 
NA, 24, 26.7, 16.6, NA, 26.9, 16.9, 21.3, 15.9, 27.4, 13.9, NA, 
20, NA, 12.8, NA, 33.8, 18.1, NA, NA, 28.4, 10.9, 38.1, 33, 39.3, 
15.9, 32.7, NA, 20.4, 16.8, NA, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: @Luca Please **edit your question** with additional information. Don't put them in a comment.

Comment: Thanks both. I just added an example of the chart with reprex, and dataset example with dput

Comment: @Luca Are you strongly depending on `ggplot`? I find this easier to achieve with base plots.

Comment: @jay.sf I'm happy to use base plots instead if it allows me to add the labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I recommend clean column names.

```
dat <- dataset
names(dat) <- tolower(gsub("\\s", "\\.", names(dat)))
```

Whith base R plots you could do the following. The clou is, that you can store the quantiles and custom positions to use them as coordinates later which gives you a dynamic positioning. I'm not sure if/how this is possible with `ggplot`.

```
plot(density(dat$estimated.percent.body.fat, na.rm=TRUE), ylim=c(0, .05), 
     main="Density curve")
abline(v=c1 <- dat$estimated.percent.body.fat[12], col="red")
abline(v=q1 <- quantile(dat$estimated.percent.body.fat, .05, na.rm=TRUE), col="grey")
abline(v=q2 <- quantile(dat$estimated.percent.body.fat, .95, na.rm=TRUE), col="grey")
text(c1 + 4, .05, c(expression("" %<-% "custom")), cex=.8)
text(q1 - 5.5, .025, c(expression("5% percentile" %->% "")), cex=.8)
text(q2 + 5.5, .025, c(expression("" %<-% "95% percentile")), cex=.8)
```

[image]

*Note:* Case you don't like the arrows just do e.g. `"5% percentile"` instead of `c(expression("5% percentile" %->% ""))`.

Or in `ggplot` you could use `annotate`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`)) + 
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`[12]), 
             color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = quantile(dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`,
                                       0.05, na.rm = TRUE)), 
             color = "grey", size = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = quantile(dataset$`Estimated percent body fat`,
                                       0.95, na.rm = TRUE)), 
             color="grey", size=0.5) +
  annotate("text", x=16, y=.05, label="custom") +
  annotate("text", x=9.5, y=.025, label="5% percentile") +
  annotate("text", x=38, y=.025, label="95% percentile")
```

[image]

***Note,*** that in either solution the result (i.e. exact label positions) depends on your export size. To learn how to control this, take e.g. a look into [**How to save a plot as image on the disk?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144203/6574038).

---

***Data***

```
dataset <- structure(list(`Respondent sequence number` = c(21029L, 21034L, 
21043L, 21056L, 21067L, 21085L, 21087L, 21105L, 21107L, 21109L, 
21110L, 21125L, 21129L, 21138L, 21141L, 21154L, 21193L, 21195L, 
21206L, 21215L, 21219L, 21221L, 21232L, 21239L, 21242L, 21247L, 
21256L, 21258L, 21287L, 21310L, 21325L, 21367L, 21380L, 21385L, 
21413L, 21418L, 21420L, 21423L, 21427L, 21432L, 21437L, 21441L, 
21444L, 21453L, 21466L, 21467L, 21477L, 21491L, 21494L, 21495L
), `Estimated percent body fat` = c(NA, 7.2, NA, NA, 24.1, 25.1, 
30.2, 23.6, 24.3, 31.4, NA, 14.1, 20.5, NA, 23.1, 30.6, 21, 20.9, 
NA, 24, 26.7, 16.6, NA, 26.9, 16.9, 21.3, 15.9, 27.4, 13.9, NA, 
20, NA, 12.8, NA, 33.8, 18.1, NA, NA, 28.4, 10.9, 38.1, 33, 39.3, 
15.9, 32.7, NA, 20.4, 16.8, NA, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf and very good remark on storing the quantiles to use them as coordinates later, i will do it as soon as the label code is working. Your example works, however I would like to make the positioning of the label to be dynamic. I want to use the same code in different datasets (datasets are dynamically generated), and in other datasets the right y positioning might be 0.07, or 0.03 etc

Comment: In the base solution you get dynamic positioning, though?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have dynamic positioning in my base solution.. the dynamic positioning is the part i really want to add

Comment: In e.g. `text(c1 + 4...`, `c1` dynamically depends on your custom value. I consider this as dynamic. The `+ 4` depends on label length which always stays the same.

Comment: Good point. I think the main issue is the y positioning: while now the maximum in the y axis is 0.05, it might be 0.1 in a different dataset. Regarding the x axis, I agree that your solution is dynamic, however with a different dataset (example: maximum is 30 instead of 40), then the +4 would become a bit too much or a bit too little.

Comment: For x positioning, I imagine I can calculate the maximum for my x axis with a formula from my dataset. Then based on that, estimate the spacing for the label. For y positioning, I tried to look for a formula that gives me the maximum but I couldn't find it. Thank you @jay.sf for you help!

Comment: For the y axis you could use the maximum of your density distribution, e.g. `max(density(dat$estimated.percent.body.fat, na.rm=TRUE)$y)`.