# How to save an image on a machine without graphic devices?

Tags: r, plot

On a virtual machine on Azure, the following code produces a file with 4 KB that cannot be opened by a viewer:

```
pdf(pdf_filepath)
ggplot2::ggplot(...)
dev.off()
```

The code with `png("...png")` fails to even produce an image.

How to save a plot on a virtual machine without graphic devices?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `ggplot2`, you can use `ggsave`:

```r
gplot2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(...)
ggsave(filepath, plot = gplot2, width = 14, height = 5, units = 'cm')
```

Also mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk/13429099#13429099).