# How to edit the legend of calibration plot?

Tags: r

I draw a calibration plot with the R code from:http://rpubs.com/IL2/519772

```
require(rms)
library(Hmisc)
library(grid)
library(lattice)
library(Formula) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(survival)
library(survival)
data(lung)

lung$sex <- factor(lung$sex,levels = c(1,2),labels = c("male", "female"))
dd=datadist(lung)
options(datadist="dd") 
fit1<- lrm(status~ age + sex+ ph.karno,x=T,y=T, data = lung) 
cal1 <- calibrate(fit1,X=T,Y=T, method='boot',m=76,B=228)

plot(cal1,lwd=2,lty=1,
 cex.lab=1.2, cex.axis=1, cex.main=1.2, cex.sub=0.6,
 xlim = c(0,1),ylim= c(0,1),
 xlab="Nomogram-Predicted Probability of death risk",
 ylab="Actual death (proportion)",
 col=c("#00468BFF","#ED0000FF","#42B540FF")
 )

 lines(cal1[,c(1:3)], 
  type ="o", 
  lwd = 1, 
  pch = 16, 
  col=c("#00468BFF"))

abline(0,1,lty = 3, 
   lwd = 2, 
   col = c("#224444")
   )
```

However, my plot cannot show all the legend of "apparent, Bias-corrected, Ideal".

[image]
How to edit the plot like the following?
[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I don't think it's always reasonable to expect readers here on SO to read through the remote article and run all of its code trying to get to the point where this question becomes relevant. Further, it is generally better to keep questions here on SO as self-contained as possible; while I would not expect rpubs links to go stale, if it does ... this question as-is becomes useless.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments about the formatting, I revised the details.

Comment: link is dead.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `legend=FALSE` option and create a custom `legend` and define exact positions.

```
plot(cal1, lwd=2, lty=1, 
     cex.lab=1.2, cex.axis=1, cex.main=1.2, cex.sub=0.6, 
     xlim=c(0, 1), ylim= c(0, 1), 
     xlab="Nomogram-Predicted Probability of death risk", 
     ylab="Actual death (proportion)", 
     col=c("#00468BFF", "#ED0000FF", "#42B540FF"),
     legend=FALSE)

lines(cal1[, c(1:3)], type ="o", lwd=1, pch=16, col=c("#00468BFF"))

abline(0, 1, lty=3, lwd=2,  col=c("#224444")) 

legend(x=.6, y=.4, legend=c("Apparent", "Bias-corrected", "Ideal"), 
       lty=c(3, 1, 2), bty="n")
```

[image]

As you just found out on your own, to make the legend even narrower we can use option `y.intersp` inside `legend`, e.g. `legend(... y.intersp=.8)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful suggestions. However, the spaces among the three legends are too wide in my version, how can I change that? thank you again.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved the problem of legend space: legend(x=.5, y=.4, legend=c("Apparent", "Bias-corrected", "Ideal"), lty=c(3, 1, 2), bty="n",y.intersp=0.3)

Comment: Nice! Consider, that it may look different when you [export the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144203/6574038).