# How to plot survival probability calibration with Lifelines?

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression, calibration, cox, lifelines

I am trying to use `survival_probability_calibration` to visualize the performance of Cox model but the calibration curve would always stay flat as shown in the following plot:
[Calibration curve with cox model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6rq7.png)

What can be the reason of this issue? Does any other package like matplotlib affect this plot?

Comment: This appears to be an effort to emulate the features of the R package rms. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710848/how-to-edit-the-legend-of-calibration-plot

Comment: @IRTFM What's wrong with that? It is tagged `lifelines`....

Comment: I didn’t say there was anything wrong with trying to emulate the rms package. I was trying to offer a place to look for a particular functionality that appears to be ineffective in the hands of the OP using lifelines. Since he offered no code or data the question seems mostly useless from a debugging perspective and should probably be closed.