# Code equivalent of RStudio Export > Save as Image?

Tags: r, rstudio

Suppose we wish to generate many plots and have them save (e.g in a loop or long script).

There are numerious `*save*` functions, many which appear to be specific to the type of plot/image being saved.

[image]

However, RStudio's Export > Save as Image seems very reliable and versatile, plus offers the ability to set the image format (from a drop down), and Width/Height, which is fantastic.

Is there a **code equivalent** of it (including the ability to select image type, hight and width)?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a plot as image on the disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Comment: `dev.print` from the accepted answer might be what you're looking for, since it accepts the device (pdf, png, jpg, etc.) as an argument

Comment: @divibisan interesting. I definitely prefer to just use a single function. It means far fewer conditionals in code, and (even if this is not a great reason) it's a few fewer things to have to remember (i.e. it would be easy to look at available image formats with `?all_encompassing_save_fn` than have to recall all the available formats. I wlll look further into `dev.print`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, similarfunctions exists for exporting in other formats.

```
pdf("filename.pdf", width=123, height=456)

plot()
...

dev.off()
```

Similar functions exists for exporting in other formats. such as `bmp()`, `jpeg()`, `png()`, and `tiff()`

**Edit:**

if you were looking to make a way to choose the filetype by variable you could implement this approach:

```
export.type <- "jpeg"
export.filename <- "plot1.jpeg"
export.height <- 123
export.width<- 123

export.func <- paste0(export.type,"(",export.filename,",height=",export.height,",width=",export.width,")")

eval(parse(text="export.func"))
```

you create a string of your function from variables, then evaluate it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there one single more general function that accepts the image format as an argument? (rather than needing a separate function for each image format)?

Comment: @stevec not as you describe, but all those image formats take the same arguments for the most part. So you could just swap the function name.

Comment: @stevec I've added a "janky" way of accomplishing your goal.