# how to enlarge the text in legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, box

I use this code

```
legend("topright", legend = c("Sub_metering_1", "Sub_metering_2", "Sub_metering_3"),
       col = c("black","red","blue"),lty = 1,cex = 0.5, y.intersp = 0.2,)
```

and I have this legend.

[image]

but I want to enlarge the text, something like this,

[image]

but without enlarging the box.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Normally enlarging `cex=` should work. How do you save your plot? If you use rstudio preview window, try a more sophisticated method: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7144118/6574038

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
legend("topright", legend = c("Sub_metering_1", "Sub_metering_2", "Sub_metering_3"),
       col = c("black","red","blue"),lty = 1,cex = 1, y.intersp = 0.2,)
```

I changed the value: cex = 1