# Legend scatterplot

Tags: r, plot

I created some scatterplots but somehow the inscription in the legend box doesn't show right. It should say "D", "K" but somehow both letters are being fused. What can I do? Also, I would like the legend box to be a bit bigger. Thanks a lot!

And here's my code:

```
    plot(FB_MW$Trauer, w2v$trauer,
     main = "Trauer", 
     xlab = "Rating Fragebogen (MW)", 
     ylab = "word2vec",
     col  = w2v$color,
     pch=16)
legend("bottomright", legend=c("D", "K"),
       pch=16,
       col=c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Your plot looks to me scaled in the plot window; just re-run the code to re-build the legend automatically in appropriate size, or use `cex=` argument to scale the legend. You also may want to use a more sophisticated, i.e. code-based saving method, read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144203/6574038

Comment: Ok, thank you! I put cex = .8 and it worked fine!