# How can I get the dates on a multi-year plot to display as month names?

Tags: r, date, plot, graph, axis

Here is the code, datereal has 517 date values from 2020-02-01 to 2020-06-30.
Plot is produced as per image.
Ideally I would like a tick mark for each month and alternating months i.e. Feb 20, Apr20 ....May 21, Jul 21.

```
dev.new(width=12, height=7.5) 
# Adjust the margin of plot (bottom,left,top,right)
par(mar=c(5, 5, 3, 7))
plot(datereal, base9, type = "l", lwd=2, col = "blue", xaxt = "n", xlab="Month",ylab="Daily new cases ")
#plot(datereal, base9, type = "l", lwd=2, col = "blue", xaxt = "n", xlab="              2020                Month                     2021",
#ylab="Daily new cases ")
axis.Date(1, datereal, 
         at = seq(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2021-06-01"), by = "1 month"))
```

[Rplot showing x axis with years not months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql6PK.png)

Comment: Try inserting `, format=strftime(dte, "%b")` after the `at=` argument. See `?strftime` for more options. You need to specify what to print on the axis in addition to where to print.

Answer (score 0):

To get the label positions on the first of each month, we use `substr`.

One way is to use two-month intervals as you have indicated. For this we may generate sequences 1, 2, 3, ... along the dates, using `seq_along`, and look where they are zero in modulo 2 to get the subset IDs `ids`. To get the month-year format we use `format=` (see `?strftime` for options).

```
op <- par(mar=c(5, 5, 3, 7))  ## set par
plot(datereal, base9, type="l", lwd=2, col="blue", xaxt="n", xlab="Month",
     ylab="Daily new cases")
which(substr(datereal, 9, 10) == "01")
labs <- datereal[substr(datereal, 9, 10) == "01"]
ids <- seq_along(labs)[(seq_along(labs) + 1) %% 2 == 0]
axis.Date(1, at=labs[ids], format="%b %y", cex.axis=.9)
par(op)  ## reset par
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can rotate the text ninety degrees (but the first variant is nicer). This is possible using `mtext`. We still need `axis` to get the tick marks.

```
op <- par(mar=c(5, 5, 3, 7))
plot(datereal, base9, type="l", lwd=2, col="blue", xaxt="n", xlab="Month",
     ylab="Daily new cases")
axis(1, at=labs, labels=FALSE)
mtext(strftime(labs, format="%b %y"), side=1, line=.75, at=labs, las=2, cex=.8)
par(op)
```

[image]

**Note,** you appear to be working with the Plot window and saving images by mouse click. If you rescale the window, the labels may disappear. A better choice is to use, for example, the `png` device as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7144203/6574038)

---

*Data:*

```
base9 <- 5e5*dnorm(seq(-2, 14, length=516), 10, 4)
datereal <- seq(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2021-06-30"), "day")
```