# Why are my plots are stretched when using mfrow()?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to fit in 13 plots in one image but the plots in the image seem to be stretched and is not clear.

[image: My Problem]

This is currently my coding progress:

```
par(mfrow=c(4,4))
plot(johordata,series = "male", main = "Johor")
plot(kedahdata,series = "male", main = "Kedah")
plot(kelantandata,series = "male", main = "Kelantan")
plot(melakadata,series = "male",main = "Melaka" )
plot(nsembilandata,series = "male",main = "Negeri Sembilan")
plot(pahangdata,series = "male",main = "Pahang")
plot(perakdata,series = "male",main = "Perak")
plot(perlisdata,series = "male",main = "Perlis")
plot(ppinangdata,series = "male",main = "Pulau Pinang")
plot(sabahdata,series = "male",main = "Sabah")
plot(sarawakdata,series = "male",main = "Sarawak")
plot(selangordata,series = "male",main = "Selangor")
plot(terengganudata,series = "male",main = "Terengganu")
```

Thus, I'm trying to figure out the right way for the 13 plots to look like this:

[image: Like this]

Comment: How are you outputting the plots? pdf, jpeg, png? Read the manuals they have height and width arguments. You need to fix the aspect ratio so that every plot appears more square.

Answer (score 1):

As *@zx8754* said in the comments, you should use the `png` or `pdf` device, to make the result independent of the current scaling of your plots window. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7144118/6574038). In addition you may want to screw a little more on the `par` options, e.g. using `mar=`. Just read `?par` help file. *Example:*

```
png("X:/plot1.png", width=480, height=480)
op <- par(mfrow=c(4, 4), mar=c(4, 4, 2.5, 1.5))  ## set pars and store defaults
replicate(16, plot(mpg ~ hp, mtcars, col=4))
par(op)  ## reset par defaults
dev.off()
```

[image]