# Export plot to disk with predefined size, R

Tags: r, plot, export

Something similar like this [How to save a plot as image on the disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7144118/15235792) but I need also to adjust the plot size, so let's say the exported plot should have a `width` of 1000 and a `height` of 746. How can I predefine such size parameter in the code?

Comment: `png(filename = "Rplot%03d.png",
    width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", pointsize = 12)` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R's graphics devices have `width` and `height` arguments, that can be set to specified values.
Here is an example with device `png()`.

```
png(filename = "mtcars.png", width = 1000, height = 746)

plot(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
abline(lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars), col = "blue", lty = "dashed")

dev.off()
```