# How to save a plot in .png format in R

Tags: r, plot, save-as

I made this plot in R:

```
plot(OHR_VIX_P$OHR),col=red,ylab=OHR)
```

Then, I assign it to a variable:

```
AR_VIX <-  plot(OHR_VIX_P$OHR),col=red,ylab=OHR)
```

And I want to savein .png format to a file in my R proyect, the file name is 00_Data I tried with the code:

```
    png(file=here("00_Data/AR_VIX.png"),
    width=600, height=350)
    dev.off()
```

It was saved on my file but it it not a .png image, actually it is nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: I think you need  `png(file=here("00_Data/AR_VIX.png"),
    width=600, height=350); plot(OHR_VIX_P$OHR,col=red,ylab=OHR); dev.off()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a plot as image on the disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Comment: The `plot` closing bracket had a typo

Comment: Thanks! I was abble to save it with your help!