# Image each slice of array in r using apply function

Tags: r, arrays, image, matrix, apply

I have an array with dimensions 32x32x1000. I want to image all the slices of this array using the `image` and `apply` functions. The 1000 pictures would be displayed as a 25x40 plot. However, I am able to visualize only the first slice.

Here is my code:

```
par(mfrow = c(25, 40))

data <- array(data = b, dim = c(32,32,2000))

apply(data, c(1,2), FUN = image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` along margin `3`. *Example:*

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
apply(A, MARGIN=3L, image)
par(op)
```

[image]

You probably will run into `figure margins too large` issues, which refers to the "preview" plotting device, so you may want to try one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7144118/6574038) remedies. Also visit `help('par')` on how to adjust some other graphical parameters such as `mar=`.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
A <- replicate(4, matrix(runif(10*10), 10))
```