# Is there a way to disable autocorrect in RStudio when saving plots?

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

I am trying to figure out how to prevent RStudio from autocorrecting and autocapitalizing file names when manually saving plots as images (plots > export > save as image > ) When I type the intended filename, RStudio almost always autocompletes the text or capitalizes the first letter, which I find extremely annoying.

The "Spelling" option in Preferences doesn't provide a way to disable this feature. I've looked through the rest of the Preferences options and have searched Stack Exchange to no avail.

I am using R version 3.6.3. and RStudio version 1.1.456. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7144118/6574038) solution and become professional.

Comment: @jay.sf I figured someone was going to say that :)