# Why is ggsave not saving my plot to my computer?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

Hi I'm trying to save high quality (300 dpi) images using RStudio but no luck so far. I've looked around a lot on the internet but no answer seems to work. Even when I run the code below, no file shows up on my computer. Any help is appreciated!

```
install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)
data("gapminder")

attach(gapminder)

plot(lifeExp ~ log(gdpPercap))
ggsave("filename.png",dpi = 300)
```

Comment: `ggsave` is meant to work with `ggplot` objets. The `plot()` function uses base R graphics and is not related so `ggplot` at all. So do you want to save base graphics? If so, see this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk. Otherwise you'll actually need to create your plot using the `ggplot` function and syntax in order to use `ggsave`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine if you use `ggplot()` from `ggplot2` instead of `plot()`

**Packages and data**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)

data("gapminder")
attach(gapminder)
```

### Solution

```
ggplot(gapminder,
       aes(x =  log(gdpPercap), y = lifeExp)) +
  geom_point()

ggsave("filename.png",dpi = 300)
```

Here are some tweaks you came make to make it more similar to    `plot()` appearance:

```
ggplot(gapminder,
       aes(x =  log(gdpPercap), y = lifeExp)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  theme_linedraw()
```

**output from last code**

[image]