# Automatically exporting images from R studio

Tags: r, image, export

I am processing some data that creates a lot of images (maps).
I've made it so that I can automatically generate the maps, however I have a number of problems that I can't figure out.
Each map created relates to an `April.day` in the df

Here is the first 50 rows of the dataframe

```
dput(df_NS)
structure(list(Nestbox = c("O242", "O51", "O59", "O71", "C110", 
"C116", "C120", "C13", "C132", "C134", "C139", "C140", "C29", 
"C30", "C33", "C48", "C56", "C9A", "MP25", "MP67", "B30", "MP2", 
"B101", "B11", "B112", "B15", "B197", "B2", "B217", "B22", "B30", 
"B95", "MP21", "MP25", "MP33", "MP51", "MP56", "MP6", "MP60", 
"MP61", "MP67", "MP77", "EX84", "EX92", "SW130", "O31", "O38", 
"O38B", "O48", "O58"), April.day = c(-25, -22, -22, -22, -14, 
-14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, 
-23, -23, -20, -20, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, 
-11, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, 
-10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10), State.code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), lon = c(-1.341280663, 
-1.343562025, -1.343620358, -1.340629756, -1.332551665, -1.329108814, 
-1.328655294, -1.330835311, -1.330715028, -1.33052464, -1.328144549, 
-1.328287425, -1.329353862, -1.329343236, -1.33041446, -1.325353001, 
-1.327279282, -1.332909331, -1.300122834, -1.299148682, -1.310197641, 
-1.305886812, -1.308725397, -1.309505208, -1.309235075, -1.308580716, 
-1.30959055, -1.308685087, -1.309426224, -1.306562029, -1.310197641, 
-1.307564253, -1.301598673, -1.300122834, -1.299510666, -1.299846899, 
-1.297823339, -1.305388627, -1.297220016, -1.297398331, -1.299148682, 
-1.300378324, -1.333554619, -1.338688389, -1.332015649, -1.344951753, 
-1.344769267, -1.345214102, -1.342514477, -1.343145083), lat = c(51.76635545, 
51.76553293, 51.76450781, 51.76428383, 51.75689245, 51.75615401, 
51.75742817, 51.75637019, 51.75666667, 51.75740286, 51.7596281, 
51.75976378, 51.75721637, 51.75695556, 51.75701561, 51.75871255, 
51.75875955, 51.75720018, 51.76339382, 51.75986347, 51.76597134, 
51.76737513, 51.76464054, 51.76481595, 51.76542577, 51.76557477, 
51.76682149, 51.7644335, 51.76714421, 51.76681267, 51.76597134, 
51.76571265, 51.76447255, 51.76339382, 51.76268887, 51.76062289, 
51.76030512, 51.76678776, 51.75996884, 51.75968219, 51.75986347, 
51.75998767, 51.76749876, 51.76822905, 51.76474771, 51.76863319, 
51.76622254, 51.7655237, 51.76482531, 51.76430735)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
    April.day = c(-25, -23, -22, -20, -20, -14, -14, -11, -11, 
    -11, -10, -10, -10), State.code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .rows = structure(list(1L, 19:20, 
        2:4, 22L, 21L, c(7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
        17L), c(5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 18L), 23:30, 32L, 31L, c(33L, 
        35L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 47L, 50L), c(34L, 36L, 37L, 
        38L, 39L, 40L, 44L, 46L, 49L), 48L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -13L), .drop = TRUE))
```

and this is the code that I've been working with

```
df_split <- df_NS %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  split(.$April.day)

statecol<- colorFactor(palette = "viridis", df_NS$State.code) #create the colour palette

plot_fun <- function(ix) {
  x<- do.call(rbind, df_split[seq(ix)])
  leaflet() %>% 
    setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 13.25) |> 
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = x, label = ~as.character(x$Nestbox), radius = 5, color = ~statecol(State.code), stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 5) %>%
    addLegend('bottomright', pal = statecol, values = x$State.code,
              title = 'Nest State',
              opacity = 2)  
}

plots <- lapply(seq_along(Nestates_NS_split), plot_fun)




plotnumbers<- length(plots)



for( i in 1:plotnumbers)  {
  print(plots[[i]])
}
```

I would like to automatically export all the images created to a folder inside the working directory, with the corresponding `April.day` in the filename and then annotate the image with the `April.day` in the dataframe.

Previously I would have exported each file using the export image feature in R studio but that is tedious.
Then I would annotate the images using something like this from the `magick` package

```
install.packages("magick")
library(magick)
#first read in the image
ns0104<- image_read("C:.../Images for gifs/NS0104.png")
#annotate the image
ns0104<-image_annotate(ns0104, "4th April", size = 30, color = "black", gravity = "north", boxcolor = "white" )
# Save the annotated file
image_write(ns0104,"ns0104.png" )
```

Then combine the images to a GIF

```
list.files(path = "C:.../Images for gifs", pattern = "*.png", full.names = T) %>% 
  map(image_read) %>% # reads each path file
  image_join() %>% # joins image
  image_animate(fps=2, delay = 150) %>% # animates, can opt for number of loops
  image_write("map.gif")
```

So as you can see to do this manually for more than 25 images would be really tedious

Any help appreciated, also open to other more efficient methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a plot as image on the disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Comment: Thanks @Caspar but not really. all of these require going through each individual image.

Comment: use a `for` loop or `lapply` to iterate over them.