# enlarge window plot Rstudio

Tags: r, plot

I would like to present some ORs in the form of a forest plot. I have found how to do this but I have too many results and not all of them fit on the graph... even if I stretch the plot window on R as much as possible, I don't have the whole plot.

I have already tried to reduce the margins but it is always too small

I would like to know if there was another way to do it, to enlarge the window or something else

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7144118/6574038

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't have all my results yet but it's much better if I save it as a png. I'll try to play with the settings to get it right

Comment: you can also use `x11()` (on windows) before plotting which opens a new window instead of plotting inside the rstudio console