# Save last displayed plot (like or using ggsave)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

### Explanation

Using `ggplot2` and `ggsave` it is possible to save the last displayed plot:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:10,
                         y = 1:10),
       aes(x = x,
           y = y)) +
 geom_point()

ggsave(filename = 'test.png',
       device = 'png')
```

However, `ggsave` does not save plots created without `ggplot2`:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(1:10)
plot(10:1)

par(mfrow = c(1, 1))

ggsave(filename = 'test.png',
       device = 'png')
```

### Background information

Some of the single plots like `plot(1:10)` are (a) created by calling `plot` on specific objects or (b) created by calling specific methods from packages.

I am also interested in solving "the same" problem when using `layout` instead of `par`.

### Question

Is there a way to achieve this? For example by adding something like an empty ggplot2-layer? Or by using a more straight forward `ggplot2`-plot?

### Clarification

To be clear: I do not want to use the following code:

```
png(filename = 'test.png')

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(1:10)
plot(10:1)

par(mfrow = c(1, 1))

dev.off()
```

Comment: Do you want `dev.copy()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a plot as image on the disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`recordPlot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/recordplot.html).

```r
old_par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(1:10)
plot(10:1)
```

[image]

```r
par(old_par)

p <- recordPlot()

p
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>