# How to increase size of output from multiple plots in R

Tags: r, plot, stan

I am trying to adjust the height and width of the output comprised of the plots of the posterior draws of multiple variables, using the `mcmc_combo()` function (trace and density plots), as the size does not scale with the number of variables:

Code sample:

```
library(cmdstanr)
library(bayesplot)
library(dplyr)

draws <- fit2$draws(
    variables = param[-5],
    inc_warmup = TRUE,
    format = "df"
)
pars <- grep("lam", names(draws), value = TRUE)

mcmc_combo(draws, pars = pars)
```

Output:
[image: image|500x500]
As the image shows, the graphs get too truncated to display the y-axis altogether.

I then tried plotting the variables one-by-one, using `lapply()`:

```
lapply(pars, function(x) {mcmc_combo(draws, pars = x)})
```

[image: image|500x500]

[image: image|500x500]
As you can see, the plot window remains the same size, and the graph(s) are stretched to fit the window.

It would be better if I could fix the size of each individual graph, and have the plot window adapt to this instead. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Using a different device such as `png` or `pdf` as described [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk/7144203#7144203). The trick is to adjust `height=` parameter. You can also play around with graphical parameters such as `?mar` (as long as your method it doesn't use grids).

```
set.seed(42)

png('foo.png', width=400, height=1200)
par(mfrow=c(9, 2))
lapply(seq_len(18), \(i) hist(rnorm(100), "FD", col=4)) |> invisible()
dev.off()
```

[image]

Consider RStudio plot visualization as a preview window.