# R: cairo_pdf output in a cycle produces no files

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

I'm trying to generate multiple PDF plots by using `cairo_pdf`:

```
c <- 1
for (q in unique(resp$ques)) {
  cairo_pdf(sprintf("./imgs/q%1$d.pdf", c), width=16, height=9)
  ggplot(resp[resp$ques==q,], aes(x=dep, y=answ)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar") +
    coord_flip()
  dev.off()
  c <- c + 1
}
```

But this produces no files at all. Meanwhile, if I run the code inside `for {}` manually (i.e. after running the above code, I just run the code in the braces line by line), it does make one PDF as expected.

How to implement this idea correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that's a duplicate. Solution is here:

[ggplot's qplot does not execute on sourcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675066/ggplots-qplot-does-not-execute-on-sourcing)

In short, I needed to do `print(ggplot(..))` for `cairo_pdf` to capture the output.