# why ggplot source code doesn't display the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm stating using `ggplot2`. Here is my first code to display data from a csv file

```
w <- read.csv(file="test.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")
p <- ggplot(data=w, aes(x=start, y=current, color=cpu))
p + layer(geom="point", geom_params=list(size=2))
```

Here is a part of the file

```
start,end,active,duration,current,previous,cpu,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,
525255,0,0,0,__sto,1756,1757,0,0,0,0,0,0,
525292,525306,14,14,s_w,1756,0,0,1,0x36cd9000,29,0x00000000,29,
525313,525317,4,4,s_w,1756,0,0,1,0x36cd9000,27,0x00000000,27,
525323,0,0,0,__sto,1751,1756,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

So to run it I followed these require steps

1- install the `ggplot2` package

> install.packages("ggplot2")

2- load the `ggplot2` library into the R session

> library("ggplot2")

3- run the code which is store in the file `trace.r`

> source("trace.r")

But nothing is display.

Any idea about what is missing will be appreciate

Comment: Try `print(p + layer(geom="point", geom_params=list(size=2)))` in place of the last line of your R file.

Comment: Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675066/ggplots-qplot-does-not-execute-on-sourcing).

Comment: @VincentGuillemot that's it ! can you write it down as an answer so that I will accept ? thank for your time.