# Nested call of ggplot fails to generate plot, except when plot call comes last

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, environments

I have a function:

```
MakeTxHistogram <-function(d,x,plot.labels) {
  print(dim(d))
  ggplot(data=d) +
    geom_histogram(aes_string(x=x,y="..density..",fill="var1")) + 
    scale_x_log10() + facet_grid( var1~ var2 ) +  labs(title=plot.labels[1],x=plot.labels[2]) +
    theme
}
```

`MakeTxHistogram` does exactly what I want when called directly from a script or the console. So I created a new function:

```
TestAndPlot<-function() {
 MakeTxHistogram(d1,x,plot.labels)
 MakeTxHistogram(d2,x,plot.labels)
 RunAStatisticalTest()
}
```

When I call `TestAndPlot()`, then both calls of `MakeTxHistogram(...)` execute, but no plot is generated (the `print()` function works, however). If instead I write `TestAndPlot` as:

```
TestAndPlot<-function() {
 RunAStatisticalTest()
 MakeTxHistogram(d1,x1,plot.labels1)
 MakeTxHistogram(d2,x2,plot.labels2)
}
```

Then `RunAStatisticalTest()` works, the first call of `MakeTxHistogram` executes but does not generate a plot, and the second call of `MakeTxHistogram` executes *and* successfully generates the plot.

Have tried implementing solutions such as those suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r), including setting the `environment` to the local environment, and (obviously) using `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`. Can anyone suggest the source of the problem and a possible solution? I can just go back to calling these functions directly, but would rather be able to nest them inside of something (or understand why I can't/shouldn't do that).

Thanks!

Comment: You need to `print()` your plots. Without an explicit `return()`, only the last object from a function is returned a printed implicitly.

Comment: It's essentially the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6675610/2372064 and part of the R FAQ list: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you!