# Modify external R script in a knitr chunk

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

I'm wondering if it's possible to hook into the code in an external R script that is read by `knitr`.

Specifically, say that you have the following R file

#### `test.R`

```r
## ---- CarPlot
library(ggplot2)
CarPlot <- ggplot() +
    stat_summary(data = mtcars,
                 aes(x = factor(gear),
                     y = mpg
                     ),
                 fun.y = "mean",
                 geom = "bar"
                 )
CarPlot
```

Imagine that you wanted to use this graph in multiple reports, but in one of these reports you want the graph to have a title and in the other report you do not.

Ideally, I would like to be able to use the same external R script to be able to do this so that I do not have to make changes to multiple R files in case I decide to change something about the graph.

I thought that one way to perhaps do this would be by setting the `fig.show` chunk option to `hold`—since it will "[hold all plots and output them in the very end of a code chunk](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options)"—and then appending a title to the plot like so:

#### `test.Rnw`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<external-code, cache=FALSE,echo=FALSE>>=
read_chunk('./test.R')
@

<<CarPlot,echo=FALSE,fig.show='hold'>>=
CarPlot <- CarPlot + ggtitle("Plot about cars")
@

\end{document}
```

This, however, does not work. Although the plot is printed, the title that I tried to append does not show up.

Is there some way to do what I would like to do?

Comment: "does not work" is a poor descriptor. If you mean you didn't see a plot, that's because that code wouldn't print the plot normally, just like `x <- 1` doesn't print `x`. You need to explicitly `print(CarPlot)`, or just call it on a line by itself `CarPlot` after modifying it. Setting `fig.show` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Gregor It shows the plot, but the plot does not have the title I tried to append in the `.Rnw` file. If you look at the `test.R` file you will see that there is indeed a call to `CarPlot` on a line by itself. I don't understand how `fig.show='hold'` works, but I thought that it might prevent that line from being executed until the end of the chunk (based on the description of its functionality), allowing me to append a title.

Comment: So, in the end, this boils down to R FAQ 7.22 [as seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6675066/903061)

Comment: @AdamLiter There's a call to `CarPlot` in `test.R`, but all that happens *before* your `CarPlot <- CarPlot + ggtitle("Plot about cars")` line in the following chunk. What if you remove the `CarPlot` line from `test.R`, and add it to the end of the `CarPlot` chunk?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, I understand that. What I'm trying to ask is if there's a way to effectively run `CarPlot <- CarPlot + ggtitle("Plot about cars")` before `CarPlot` without having to explicitly do that in the external R file.

Comment: `test.R` prints the plot, but since you don't want **that** chunk to print the plot (as it's still unmodified), you should change the chunk option to, say `include = FALSE`. It's your next chunk where you modify the plot. If you want to print the modified plot, you need to `print(CarPlot)` or `CarPlot` **after** you modify it by adding the title.

Comment: You don't need to remove the `CarPlot` line from `test.R`, just hide the figures for the chunk that calls `test.R`, and explicitly print the plot after you modify it as you like.

Comment: @Gregor Ah, thanks! `:)` I should have thought about that. I forgot about the `include` chunk option. Do you want to convert that into an answer? Or is there a duplicate somewhere around?

Comment: The duplicate I'd suggest is the r-faq linked above, but this isn't *just* that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to show the plot created by `test.R`, so you should set `fig.show = 'hide'` or `include = FALSE` for that chunk:

```
<<external-code, cache=FALSE,echo=FALSE,fig.show = 'hide'>>=
read_chunk('./test.R')
@
```

You *do* want to show the plot after modification, so you have to print it:

```
<<CarPlot,echo=FALSE>>=
CarPlot <- CarPlot + ggtitle("Plot about cars")
CarPlot
@
```

`fig.show = 'hold'` is used if you have a large code chunk that prints a plot in the middle, but you don't want the plot to show in your document until the end. It doesn't apply to this case.