# running Rscript containing ggplot from linux command line through Xterm

Tags: r, bash, ggplot2, xterm

I am using Xterm on a linux server so I can quickly plot data without transferring the files to my local machine. I have a R script that uses `ggplot()`, not inside a function. When I open R through Xterm I use these commands to run the script and the plot windows works fine in Xterm

```
commandArgs <- function(...) 'plotname'
source('graph.r', print.eval=TRUE))
```

However when I try from bash with Rscript, such as

```
Rscript graph.r plotname
```

The script runs but the plot window doesn't open. I know this is a ggplot problem because if I just use `plot()` inside the script the plot window works. I have tried several suggestions from this question.

[ggplot's qplot does not execute on sourcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675066/ggplots-qplot-does-not-execute-on-sourcing)

And also tried to create a bash script starting with `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript`, nothing seems to work.

Is there a solution? I need to pass an argument to the R function

Comment: Do other (base graphics) plots work?

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica I have added x11() and it works with base and ggplot, but as soon as the plot is finished the window closes. I also tried to add prompt  <- "hit spacebar to close plots"

Comment: *prompt <- "hit spacebar to close plots"* => do you mean you added a `readline ()` statement? The X11() device (or any other graphics device) will be closed when Rscript finishes. This doesn't hurt for pdf () or similar devices, as the file with the plot will persist, but an X11 () graph will be gone.